# Error while using chromedriver to take screen shot using org.openqa.selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKl0S.png)    Facing Below error while taking (org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor)
    String style = "";
    style = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("return document.getElementById(\"modalLayer\").getAttribute(\"style\")");

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.116) Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'cloudappnode1.chainsys.com', ip: '192.168.57.140', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.5' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 80.0.3987.116, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.SYBV2k}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:41272}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify} Session ID: f574977f80da997e421f3783bb669

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Hope so that helps you. I have tested at my end and it is working fine.

```
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String data = String.valueOf(executor.executeScript(
                "var styledata = document.getElementById('modalLayer').getAttribute('style');" + "return styledata;"));

        System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: I have attached image for your reference

Comment: Thank you. That will help me to replicate the issue. I will be back in a while with the solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it once.